# Commit received hooks in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

My hooks are failing after gerrit upgrade to version 2.14.2

There is a new hook which is added in this version - commit-received

What is the difference between ref-update and commit-received hooks now ? When will it be triggered ? any example ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably found this out by now, but the ref-update hook changed between 2.13 and 2.14.   See here for details: 
https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Behavior-change-in-ref_update-hook

All I did to fix the problem was to rename the ref-update hook to commit-received and it worked as before.